# Sync profiles of different software for two Windows Laptops

Tags: windows-10, sync

How can I sync everything for two PCs for the following programs and other programs:

1- Google chrome (without online syncing)
2- Winrar
3- Microsoft Office (word-excel-powerpoint)
4- Outlook 2016
5- Is it possible to have an identical windows on both of them and keep it synced by using imaging applications?

Comment: I mean to sync the profiles and settings for those apps

Comment: Are these Windows 10 computers on an Active Directory domain?  If so, you can configure [Roaming User Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079(v=ws.11).aspx) to do almost everything you want.  If not, what you desire may be problematic.